# Can decision tree in Spark MLlib return leaf index that each sample is predicted as?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I am using decision tree in Spark MLlib with Scala. Is there an implemented method that returns the index of the leaf that each sample is predicted as?

I know that in Scikit-learn the method {apply} is able to do this. I'm wondering whether similar methods exist also in MLlib.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "leafCol" parameter which will be used by the model to fill the leaf id of each sample. The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/DecisionTreeParams.html) says:

```
Param<String> leafCol()

Leaf indices column name. Predicted leaf index of each instance in each tree by preorder. (default = "")
```